# Unexpected ARN format with parameters when trying to retrieve ASM secret

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-secrets-manager

Below is a portion of my cloudformation template for an ECS task. It fetches a secret */rds/rds_secret-D2fBVv* which contains a json key-value pair secret like `{"password":"1234ABCD","dbname":"my_db"}`...

```
TaskDefinitionAPI:
Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
Properties:
  ContainerDefinitions:
    - Name: api
      Secrets:
        - Name: "DB_PASSWORD"
          ValueFrom: "arn:aws:secretsmanager:<region>:<accountid>:secret:/rds/rds_secret-D2fBVv:SecretString:password"
```

as per this documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/cfn-example_reference-secret.html).

However when creating the stack, I get the following error

> ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: Execution resource retrieval failed: unable to retrieve secret from asm: service call has been retried 1 time(s): secrets manager: failed to retrieve secret from arn:aws:secretsmanager:::secret:/rds/rds_secret-D2fBVv:SecretString:password: unexpected ARN format with parameters when trying to retrieve ASM secret

I suspect it is because I have a json key-value pair as the secret. I have tried many modifications to this, but cloudformation still complains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/secrets-envvar-secrets-manager.html) the format should be

```
"valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:aws_account_id:secret:appauthexample-AbCdEf:username1::"
```

But you have:

```
"arn:aws:secretsmanager:<region>:<accountid>:secret:/rds/rds_secret-D2fBVv:SecretString:password"
```

that should be

`arn:aws:secretsmanager:<region>:<accountid>:secret:/rds/rds_secret-D2fBVv:password::`